# Web::Scraper nested structures & elements only containing spesific data

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I have the following code to scrape a form for inputs and get the attributes id and name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use URI;
use Data::Dumper::Simple;
use Web::Scraper;

my $urlToScrape = "http://digitalarkivet.arkivverket.no/finn_kilde";

my $scrap = scraper {
    process 'div.listGroup.open > ul.grouped > li.expandable', 'data[]' => scraper {
        process 'input', 'id' => '@id', name => '@name';
        process 'label', 'label_for' => '@for';
        process 'span.listExpander ', 'Text' => 'TEXT';
        process 'ul.sublist1', 'sublist[]' => scraper {
            process 'input', 'id' => '@id', name => '@name';
            process 'label', 'label_for' => '@for';
            process 'span', 'label' => 'TEXT';
        };
    };
};

my $res = $scrap->scrape(URI->new($urlToScrape));
print Dumper($res);
```

which gives me (shortend $res to fit screen better)

```
$res = {
     'data' => [
                 {
                   'label_for' => 'ka0',
                   'sublist' => [
                                  {
                                    'label' => 'Statlig folketelling',
                                    'label_for' => 'ka0kt0',
                                    'name' => 'kt[]',
                                    'id' => 'ka0kt0'
                                  }
                                ],
                   'name' => 'ka[]',
                   'id' => 'ka0>',
                   'Text' => 'Folketellinger'
                 },
                 {
                   'sublist' => [
                                  {
                                    'label' => 'Manntall',
                                    'name' => 'kt[]',
                                    'label_for' => 'ka1kt0',
                                    'id' => 'ka1kt0'
                                  }
                                ],
                   'label_for' => 'ka1',
                   'id' => 'ka1>',
                   'name' => 'ka[]',
                   'Text' => 'Manntall'
                 },
                 ....
                 {
                   'label_for' => 'r0',
                   'sublist' => [
                                  {
                                    'label_for' => 'r0f0',
                                    'id' => 'r0f0',
                                    'name' => 'f[]',
                                    'label' => "01 Østfold"
                                  }
                                ],
                   'id' => 'r0',
                   'name' => 'r[]',
                   'Text' => "Østlandet"
                 },
                 {
                   'Text' => "Sørlandet",
                   'id' => 'r1',
                   'sublist' => [
                                  {
                                    'label_for' => 'r1f0',
                                    'name' => 'f[]',
                                    'id' => 'r1f0',
                                    'label' => '09 Aust-Agder'
                                  }
                                ],
                   'label_for' => 'r1',
                   'name' => 'r[]'
                 }
               ]
   };
```

I' have 2 issues I need to fix. First, I only want to get data for inputs having `'name' = ka[]` (at top level).

Second, I only get data for first `ul.sublist1` (If you study the page I'm scraping you can see that several "Kildekategori" have subsets of data, which are revealed if expanded/ clicked upon. Putting brackets on `Text[]` only gets me the sublist textnames, but not their attributes.

I'm thinking I might have to grab data in 2 scrapes instead, since nested values are revealed by `id` and `label_for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by scraping three times, foreach "level"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use Web::Scraper;
use Data::Dumper::Simple;

my %site;
my @res;
my $i;
my $j;
my $label_for;
my @scrape;

$site{'siteID'} = 1;
$site{'url'} = "http://digitalarkivet.arkivverket.no/finn_kilde";
$site{'name'} = "finn_kilde";

open FIL, ">$site{'name'}.csv" or die $!;
my $seperator=";";

$scrape[0] = scraper {
    process 'div.listGroup.open > ul.grouped > li.expandable', 'data[]' => scraper {
        process 'input',
            'id'    => '@id',
            'value' => '@value',
            'type'  => '@type',
            'name'  => '@name';
        process 'label', 'label_for' => '@for';
        process 'span.listExpander ', 'text' => 'TEXT';        
    };
};

$scrape[1] = scraper {
    process 'ul.sublist1 > li', 'data[]' => scraper {
        process 'input',
          'id'    => '@id',
          'value' => '@value',
          'type'  => '@type',
          'name'  => '@name';
        process 'label', 'label_for' => '@for';
        process 'span', 'text' => 'TEXT';
    }
};

$scrape[2] = scraper {
    process 'ul.sublist2 > li', 'data[]' => scraper {
        process 'input',
          'id'    => '@id',
          'value' => '@value',
          'type'  => '@type',
          'name'  => '@name';
        process 'label', 'label_for' => '@for';
        process 'span', 'text' => 'TEXT';
    }
};


for $i (0 .. $#scrape){
    $res[$i] = $scrape[$i]->scrape(URI->new($site{'url'}));
    unless  ($i) {
        print FIL join($seperator,"label_for","text","name","value","id","type")."\n";
    }
    for $j (0 .. $#{$res[$i]->{data}}) {
        if (defined($res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{label_for})){
            $label_for=$res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{label_for};    
        } else {
            $label_for="";
        }
        if (length($label_for)>0) {
            my $name=$res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{name};
            my $text=$res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{text};
            my $value=$res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{value};
            my $id=$res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{id};
            my $type=$res[$i]->{data}[$j]->{type};
            my @row=($label_for,$text,$name,$value,$id,$type);
            print FIL join($seperator,@row);
            print FIL "\n";
        }
    }
    sleep(2);
}
close FIL;
print Dumper(\@res);

1;
```